# Python removing equal lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have some equal lists in my list a:

```
a = [[a],[a],[b],[b],[c],[c]]
```

How can I remove the equal lists so that I have the following:

```
a = [[a],[b],[c]]
```

I've tried to do it with a set but it doesn't work:

```
my_set = set()
for elem in a:
    my_set.add(elem)
for x in my_set:
    print(x)
```

Comment: use tuples instead?

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
a = [['a'],['a'],['b'],['b'],['c'],['c']]
b = list()
for item in a:
    if item not in b:
        b.append(item)
```

Answer (score 3):

`numpy` is one of the options

```
import numpy as np
a = [['a'],['a'],['b'],['b'],['c'],['c']] 
np.unique(a).tolist() #  ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind using `itertools`:

```
[x for x,_ in itertools.groupby(sorted(a))]
#[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
```

If you do, convert the lists to tuples, create a set of them, and then convert back to lists:

```
list(map(list, set(map(tuple, a))))
#[['b'], ['c'], ['a']]
```

Comment: Although it’s the case in the question, just noting that this requires the equal lists to be adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of @DYZ answer that works with lists containing identical elements regardless of the order:

```
[x for x,_ in itertools.groupby(map(set, a))]
```

For example:

```
>>> a = [['a'],['a'],['b'],['b'],['c', 'a'],['a', 'c']]
>>> [list(x) for x,_ in itertools.groupby(map(set, a))]
[['a'], ['b'], ['a', 'c']]
```

If `['c', 'a']` and `['a', 'c']` are not considered equal (see comments below by @DYZ) then you can do something like this using `set()`:

```
map(list, set(map(tuple, a)))
```

Comment: `['c', 'a']` and `['a', 'c']` are not equal.

Comment: It is not clear from the original post whether or not `['c', 'a']` and `['a', 'c']` are considered equal. In fact to me the problem sounds like `['c', 'a']` and `['a', 'c']` are likely considered equal because they contain the same elements.

Comment: The OP says "lists," not "sets." Lists `['c', 'a']` and `['a', 'c']` are different. There is no uncertainty here.

Answer (score 0):

If `['c', 'a']` and `['a', 'c']` are not considered equal then you can do something like this using `set()`:

```
map(list, set(map(tuple, a)))
```

Comment: Do not post several answers to the same question. If you have several propositions, combine them and post together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension instead.

> ```
> d = [it for i, it in enumerate(a) if it not in a[0:i]]
> print(d)
> ```